# optimal subset / joint distribution prediction with machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, optimization, multivariate-analysis, joint-distribution

How can I find the optimal subset of classes for a given entity?

For context, say that we have some customers and data about these customers transactions, and a set of possible products to advertise to them. And the objective would be to find the best subset of products to advertise to a customer, such that the joint probability of purchasing all the products is maximized.

Multi-label classification is an option to this problem, but to my understanding, the classical multi-label classification using sigmoid and log-loss over multiple classes is optimizing each class independently. I want to optimize jointly given the data.

I have seen joint optimization of sentences in Language translation using RNN's, where beam search is used to select the joint optimal sequence from a set of different sequence predictions. But here, we feed in the predictions back into the model in a natural way, thus getting a probability estimate conditoinal on the previous class prediction as well as the data up to that point.

Is a similar approach common for non-sequence models, where we can get a class probability estimate conditional on other class predictions as well as the data?

Some Resources:

https://www.depends-on-the-definition.com/guide-to-multi-label-classification-with-neural-networks/

https://guillaumegenthial.github.io/sequence-to-sequence.html

https://guillaumegenthial.github.io/image-to-latex.html

Comment: You could tackle this in two separate steps: a predictive modelling step in which you would regress the probability of purchase against all your available features/predictors, and an optimisation step which would use the trained model from step 1 as the objective function to a maximisation problem. Does that makes sense?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand completely. Do you mean one model for each product in the set of possible products, and then select the highest scoring products for that customer? That is an option, but I don't think that tackles the problem of each suggestion being independent of the other suggestions? Or did I misunderstand?

Answer (score 0):

Try rulebased learning. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arules/arules.pdf shows the vignette of the R-package

Comment: Thanks, I have some familiarity with market basket analysis from reading "Elements of Statistical Learning", and it is relevant. to the context I provide. But I would be interested in knowing if there are some ways of finding a joint optimal solution using known classification techniques.